# Manipulating string/buffer of serialized object before transmitting

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android, json.net

To solve my windows vs linux line break mismatch in my android app, I was going to simply substitute all "\r\n" sub-strings with "\n" for all data coming into the app (from a ASP.NET WebAPI REST service), and doing the opposite on data going out.

This was easy enough for the inbound data, since I already had a reference to a string that held an intermediate copy of the serialized json data, **I simply did a replace on this buffer**:

```
//...    
string recieveBuffer;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
//...

WebResponse wresponse = request.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wresponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    recieveBuffer = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
recieveBuffer = recieveBuffer.Replace("\r\n","\n");
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

List<T> temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(
    recieveBuffer,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }
);
//...
```

However, there is no intermediate string/buffer holding the serialized json data before transmitting it, it all happens internal to the JsonSerializer Serialze() member:

```
//...
string url = GetUrlRequest();

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
//...

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, new UTF8Encoding(false, true));
JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);

serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, tabletData);

jsonTextWriter.Close();
streamWriter.Close();
requestStream.Close();
//...
```

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to get a hold of buffer holding the serialized json before it is transmitted so that I can substitute all "\n" strings with a "\r\n".

Comment: Why do you think your problem is with newline chars? It is device independent/platform json object.

Comment: The desktop conterpart of this mobile version needs "\r\n" to display line breaks appropriately.

Comment: Also, android will print "\r" as a space (it's not non-printable), which gives the user an opportunity to substitute a character between the "\r\n", and is why it needs to be converted to a "\n" on the way in.

Comment: Still it is not related with json, Focus on what you send in json(your object).

Comment: @L.B Doing that way will require me to "clean" all properties of any object that contains string members with line breaks. I'm trying to deal with this all in one spot, just as the read method does. I think my write routine needs a refactor to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored my write/send code as follows:

```
//...
string url = GetUrlRequest();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter);

JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, tabletData);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
string sendBuffer = sb.ToString();
sendBuffer = sendBuffer.Replace("\n","\r\n");
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
//...

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, new UTF8Encoding(false, true));
streamWriter.Write(sendBuffer);

jsonTextWriter.Close();
streamWriter.Close();
requestStream.Close();
```